# moment datapicker: subcription to KO property

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, momentjs

Working with moment datepicker in my project i can't see where my error is. 
Basically what i want to do is make a suscription to source property in order to know when th property change (the time to load to service method). So follwoing some urls i was able to build this basic example:

```
var model = {
test_date: ko.observable(new Date('2012/12/12'))        
};

ko.applyBindings(model, $("#target")[0]);

model.test_date.subscribe(function (newValue) {    

alert("new selection :" + newValue);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rolandomartinezg/x7Zt3/5/

The code above is simple and works, my trouble begin in my production code where for some strange reason the code realted to suscription is not fired. 
short example (in production code I am typescript):

```
export var fromDate = ko.observable(new Date('2012/12/12'));
fromDate.subscribe(function (newValue) {
 alert("new selection of date");
});
```

I tried find some missing reference from my jsfiddle example and my production code and both are using the same libraries (moment.js, moment-datepicker.js, moment-datepicker-ko.js,/knockout.js.
what i am doing wrong? any tip?

**UPDATE 1**: My production code converted from typescript to js:

```
define(["require", "exports", 'services/logger', '../../services/Assessment/datacontext'], function(require, exports, __logger__, __datacontext__) {
var logger = __logger__;

var datacontext = __datacontext__;    
exports.title = 'AssessmentListing';   
exports.fromDate = ko.observable(new Date('2012/12/12'));
exports.toDate = ko.observable(new Date('2012/12/12'));

function activate() {
    loadInitData();
}

exports.activate = activate;
function loadInitData() {
    var focusDate = ko.observable(new Date('2013/07/06'));
    exports.fromDate = ko.observable(firstDayOfMonth(focusDate));
    exports.toDate = ko.observable(getLastDayOfMonth(focusDate));
    // calls to services
}

function getLastDayOfMonth(focusDate) {
    var d = new Date(Date.apply(null, focusDate));
    d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 1);
    d.setDate(0);
    return d;
}

function firstDayOfMonth(focusDate) {
    var d = new Date(Date.apply(null, arguments));
    d.setDate(1);
    return d;
}
exports.toDate.subscribe(function (newValue) {
    alert("new selection :");
});

exports.fromDate.subscribe(function (newValue) {
    alert("new selection");
});
function viewAttached() {
}
exports.viewAttached = viewAttached;
})
```

**UPDATE 2: My VIEW**

```
<div class="span4">
            <span><small>From Date:</small> </span>
            <div class="input-append date" id="fromDate" >
                <input  id="fromDatePicker"  type="text" data-bind="datepicker: fromDate()" class="input-small">
                <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
            </div>
            <span><small>To Date: </small></span>
            <div class="input-append date" id="ToDate" >
                <input id="toDatePicker" type="text" data-bind="datepicker: toDate()" class="input-small">
                <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Update 3**
Trying use changeDate doesn't work because ev.date is not available.

```
export function viewAttached() {

$('#fromDatePicker').datepicker()
.on('changeDate', function (ev) {
  /*ev.date doesn't work*/
    alert('fromdate has changed');    
});

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your data binding, you have:

```
datepicker: toDate()
```

Since `toDate` is an observable, calling `toDate()` gets you the *value* of the observable, so you're passing that instead of passing the observable itself.

Try changing your binding to:

```
datepicker: toDate
```

That will enable the `datepicker` binding handler to update your observable.

**Update**:

I think this is your second problem. In this function:

```
function loadInitData() {
    var focusDate = ko.observable(new Date('2013/07/06'));
    exports.fromDate = ko.observable(firstDayOfMonth(focusDate));
    exports.toDate = ko.observable(getLastDayOfMonth(focusDate));
    // calls to services
}
```

...you are replacing the `toDate` and `fromDate` properties with new observables which do not have the subscriptions applied that the original observables do. Try attaching the subscriptions after creating these observables, or perhaps instead of creating new observables, just populate them:

```
function loadInitData() {
    var focusDate = ko.observable(new Date('2013/07/06'));
    exports.fromDate(firstDayOfMonth(focusDate));
    exports.toDate(getLastDayOfMonth(focusDate));
    // calls to services
}
```

Comment: yes, your tip is useful. i have tested in my example on fiddle that should be the reason, sadly the after to change my view the issue is still there.

Comment: Looks like `fromDate` needs the same treatment. If this still doesn't fix the production issue, you should also post how your production code calls `ko.applyBindings`; it's not clear yet how your JS ties to your view.

Comment: My web app is based on hottowel template (this template use durandal.js). how can i give you more feedback?

Comment: Somewhere, you must be establishing what the view model is for your view. If your binding isn't working right, we need to know whether your `ko.applyBindings` is being called properly. Sorry, I'm not familiar with Durandal if that's what does this call.

Comment: Ah, I see in the docs for Durandal that the view and model are *paired by convention*.

Comment: My guess is that your module isn't getting defined properly. I see that the JS is placing things in `exports` instead of returning an object. Looks like Durandal uses AMD modules, but I'm not sure how you're defining your module with your Typescript.

Comment: huumm.. as far I see binding between viewmodel and view is working since that I can see datepicker controls getting the  values what come from "fromDate" and "toDate" properties. the thing is that for some reason suscription is not working.

Comment: yes, you right, that was the problem :).. is there some way to distinguish between changes to properties fromdate and toDate done by viewmodel and changes done by the user ? (using the datepicker). maybe i should create other question :)